# JS how to add a price to an object and pass it by an argument

Tags: javascript, object, properties, arguments, price

I am new to coding and have been given this question but I am unsure of how to correct it. Dose anyone have any suggesting?

The argument product will be an object that looks like this:

```
  { type: 'Tofu slices' }
```

Add a price property to this object and set its value to the price passed in as an argument. Then return the object.

This was the answer I came up with;

```
function addPriceToProduct (product, price) {
product.price = price
return product.price
}
```

My answer is run against this;

```
describe("addPriceToProduct", () => {
it("adds a price property to the passed product set to the passed price", () => {
  const product = {
    type: "Tofu slices"
  };
  let newProduct = addPriceToProduct(product, 1.25);
  expect(newProduct).to.eql({ type: "Tofu slices", price: 1.25 });
  newProduct = addPriceToProduct(product, 1.35);
  expect(newProduct).to.eql({ type: "Tofu slices", price: 1.35 });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return product (the object) not product.price (the value of the price property)

```
function addPriceToProduct (product, price) {
    product.price = price;
    return product;
}
```